# Creating a d3.js radial chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, d3.js

I'm trying to create a very simple d3.js radial chart using the following data and following method. I keep receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` has anybody else encountered this same problem?

**UserData**

```
var userData = [
    {
        'key':'social',
        'value':1.1,
        'y':1.1,
        'y0':1.1
    },
    {
        'key':'focus',
        'value':1.1,
        'y':1.1,
        'y0':1.1
    },
    {
        'key':'activity',
        'value':1.1,
        'y':1.1,
        'y0':1.1
    }
];
```

**Appending Chart**

```
svg.selectAll(".userData")
      .data(userData)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "userData")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill","newColor")
      .style("opacity",.6)
      .style("stroke","pink")
      .style("stroke-width",7);
```

**Currnetly Produces:**

[image]

**Trying to add axies**

```
svg.selectAll(".axis")
      .data(d3.range(angle.domain()[1]))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + angle(d) * 180 / Math.PI + ")"; })
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(radius.copy().range([-5, -radius]))
      .ticks(5)
      .orient("left"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("y", 
        function (d) {
          if (window.innerWidth < 455){
            return -(window.innerHeight * .335);
          }
          else{
            return -(window.innerHeight * .335);
          }
        })
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d, i) { return capitalMeta[i]; })
      .attr("style","font-size:16px;")
      .style("fill", function(d,i) {
        if ($.inArray(meta[i], unhealthyArray) != -1) {
           return "red";
       } else {
           return "black";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple path elements (one per element in the `userData` array), as in a pie chart? Or are you trying to create a single path element for everything, as in a radial line or area chart?

Comment: Take a look at the [radial line example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/line/line-radial.html).

Comment: @mbostock and I'm adding this axis code in between the svg declaration in your example and the svg.append line

Comment: It's working, however for some reason two charts are being appended to the DOM...

Comment: There is no "d.values" property on your data. (5th line).